# How to correct magento url, it is not correct url as per admin

Tags: php, magento

I am not sure why this problem comes and how to resolve it. i never seen this type of problem before.

Please check the same categories url frontend and admin of my magento store
This is my site URl page url only the brand categories having this problem
103.16.130.92/index.php/brands/acom-1

[image]

admin

[image]

if any one can help me please help
thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
    This url brands/acom  is already exit on core_rewrite_url,again we have try
 to creating this url this then magento logic extra paramete -1
```

More details on  http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-url-rewrites/

Comment: Can you please explain me? i got all (-1) links are in catelog >> Url re write, i am not sure how it is here. can you please help me how to change it all.

Answer (score 0):

This is because same request path is already exists in Magento Rewrite Management. So, it added the id with the URL key to distinguish between the two URLs.

Go to following path in admin and search for the key in request path:

```
Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management
```

Comment: Yes, i know it but, can you help me , i have more than 700 subcategories here how can replace -1 from each.

Comment: As one URL can only be mapped to one category, you can't keep 2 categories with same URL. If the same category doesn't exist twice in your system it means you deleted the category with same name earlier from the database directly instead of admin panel.
If this is the case then you can run DB query to updated all categories at once. But make sure to back up the table once before running any query.

Comment: Can you help me on which table i will get this, or how can i do it?

Comment: I can provide you the query but before that you need to confirm your scenario - Does this category "Acom"  exists twice in your system due to which 2 categories have same url key OR did u delete categories diretly from database earlier due to which the keys are using -1 as suffix.

Comment: no it is not twice,it is once but it was define wrong on Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management. How it added wrong there i don't know,when i change the url by edit it it works fine for me. Please help me

Comment: I hv responded in a separate question..pls check that..hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First take the back up of your database before running these queries as I am not aware of your existing database condition, reason for this and type of data present there. Execute following querires

```
UPDATE core_url_rewrite SET request_path=REPLACE(request_path,"-1.html",".html") WHERE id_path LIKE "category%";
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_varchar SET `value`=REPLACE(`value`,"-1.html",".html") WHERE attribute_id=57;
```

where **57** is the attribute id for attribute **url_path**
If you get error while executing first query **(Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxx-1' for key 'UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID')** then it means the same key is already there.

I am assuming that in your table only the problematic categories will have "-1.html" as suffix.

Comment: One more thing - this is for the case when url is like www.xyz.com/brands/test-1.html...if you don't have html part in your url path then you have to modify the query accordingly...but make sure "-1" is itself capable identifying the content to be remove and is not appearing anywhere else other than the end of url.